# I was in the detached state but all my progress are now all gone after I checkout --track

Tags: git

> I was in a detached state but after I issued

```
git checkout --track origin/edit-users
```

all my changes are now gone

I just would like to ask which specific branch / commit number here should I use

I went to the .git/logs/head

```
cat .git/logs/HEAD |grep checkout | head -1
```

i was wondering if which commit hash should I use here

[image]

Cause I'm about to issue this

```
git checkout the_hash
git checkout branch_with_lost_commits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had made a commit before, you should first check out [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You would see your commit there, and can [cherry-pick it](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), if you want it back on top of your current branch.

Comment: Check on this sir,  https://pastebin.com/tjgtD7jf. I want to get back to that `b838c88`

Comment: Can I safely checkout on those ?.. cause I want the commits that I have done to that to be inside my current branch:  `edit-criminals`

Comment: @TheBAST if you want to apply that commit on top of your current branch edit-criminal, simply git cherry-pick it: https://pastebin.com/tjgtD7jf. Do not checkout it, or you would revert back to a detached HEAD.

Comment: Oops, how do I do it sir I don't want to create new issues here.. Lol

Comment: Simply `git cherry-pick b838c88` (if you have made only one commit), or `git cherry-pick older-commit-you-want..b838c88`: do that after `git checkout edit-criminal`. Read https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick